# Graphql with sails js and mysql

Tags: sails.js, graphql

I am a beginner for sails js and graphql.i do lot's of research but can't find any method for getting data from MySQL database using sails js and graphql.please help me.
I try to use sails-graphql

> npm install sails-graphql --save

Model file

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        id: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: 'integer'
        },
        Description: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    }
};
```

And graphqlController.js

```
module.exports = {
    index(req, res) { // default index action
        if (!schema) {
            schema = generateSchema.generateSchema(sails.models);
        }
        console.log(graphql.printSchema(schema));
        graphql.graphql(
            schema,                       // generated schema
            '{customer { id }}',                     // graphql query string
            null,                         // default rootValue
            {                             // context
                request: sails.request,     // default request method - required
                reqData: {                  // object of any data you want to forward to server's internal request
                    headers: {/*your headers to forward */ }
                }
            }
        ).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            // errors handling
            res.json(result.data);
        });
    }
};
```

But it's return null data everytime

```
{
    "customer": null
}
```

package github link [sails-graphql](https://github.com/zhukmj/sails-graphql)

Comment: Hey, unless you are not required to use sails I would recommend to not use sails for GraphQL. Sails is very powerful at creating REST endpoints from your models. For GraphQL there are more specialised **and better documented** frameworks available. Using `apollo-server` with `graphql-js` and an ORM might be a better beginner's solution. Questions like yours often come up because you are trying to learn to much at once. While sails can do a lot for you there is quite some magic involved (building Schema and resolvers from the models) that does not help beginners learn about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create rootValue object and instead of null put rootValue  object there in the qraphql function (Please refer below code)

```
 const rootValue = {
         customer : async () => {
         try{
             const result = await YOUR_MODEL_NAME.find()
             return result
         } catch(err) {
             return err
         } 
         }
    }

graphql.graphql(
            schema,                       // generated schema
            '{customer { id }}',                     // graphql query string
            **rootValue,**                         // defined above
            {                             // context
                request: sails.request,     // default request method - required
                reqData: {                  // object of any data you want to forward to server's internal request
                    headers: {/*your headers to forward */ }
                }
            }
        ).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            // errors handling
            res.json(result.data);
        });
```

Basically, you had not written any function to handle your request.
So Here I have just created a function **(Note: function name must match with request Query)** and put it in the object and called that object in the graphql function.. Other than that every thing seems ok..

I hope this will help you to resolve the issue :)